# Thymeleaf recognizing one of my entities

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

This was a subject I thought I had down pack but apparently I was wrong. App is crashing giving the error above and the print trace below. Ironically, App did work at one point but when I assed something it started crashing. Thanks for any ideas.

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class ManagerController {

    private ManagerService managerService;

    @Autowired
    public void setManagerService(ManagerService managerService){
        this.managerService = managerService;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/add-manager")
    public String showManagerPage(Model model){
        List<Manager> managers = managerService.findAllManagers();
        model.addAttribute("managers", managers);
        return "add-manager";
    }

    @GetMapping("/showManagerForm")
    public String addManagerForm(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("manager", new Manager());
        return "add-manager";
    }

    @PostMapping("/saveManager")
    public String postManagerForm(@ModelAttribute("manager") Manager manager){
        managerService.saveManager(manager);
        return "add-manager";
    }
}
```

Html/thymeleaf:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
<header> Welcome to Toner Stock </header>
<h1>Add Manager</h1>
<div id="mynav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="add-buyer">Add Buyer</a></li>
        <li><a href="add-manager">Add Manager</a></li>
        <li><a href="current-stock">Current Stock</a></li>
        <li><a href="transactions">Transactions</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
    <div id="display-table" align="center">
        <form th:action="@{/saveManager}" th:object="${manager}" method="post">
        <table>
            <td><label>First Name: </label></td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{firstName}"/></td>
            <td><label>Last Name: </label></td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{lastName}" /></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="save"/></td>
        </table>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="info-table" align="center">
        <table>
            <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Clients</th>
            </tr>
            <tr th:each="manager : ${managers}">
                <td th:text="${manager.firstName}"></td>
                <td th:text="${manager.lastName}"></td>
                <td>Clients</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Print Trace:

```
2017-05-14 08:46:25.800  INFO 742 --- [           main] com.ronone.Application                   : Starting Application on Ronalds-MacBook-Pro.local with PID 742 (/Users/ronaldpitt/Desktop/TonerStock/target/classes started by ronaldpitt in /Users/ronaldpitt/Desktop/TonerStock)
2017-05-14 08:46:25.805  INFO 742 --- [           main] com.ronone.Application                   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-05-14 08:46:26.076  INFO 742 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@77be656f: startup date [Sun May 14 08:46:26 EDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-05-14 08:46:27.802  INFO 742 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bd8fc63d] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-05-14 08:46:28.432  INFO 742 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-05-14 08:46:28.456  INFO 742 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2017-05-14 08:46:28.468  INFO 742 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.11
2017-05-14 08:46:28.619  INFO 742 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-05-14 08:46:28.619  INFO 742 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2548 ms
2017-05-14 08:46:28.823  INFO 742 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-05-14 08:46:28.828  INFO 742 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-05-14 08:46:28.828  INFO 742 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-05-14 08:46:28.829  INFO 742 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-05-14 08:46:28.829  INFO 742 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-05-14 08:46:29.721  INFO 742 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-05-14 08:46:29.746  INFO 742 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2017-05-14 08:46:29.856  INFO 742 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.9.Final}
2017-05-14 08:46:29.859  INFO 742 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2017-05-14 08:46:30.055  INFO 742 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2017-05-14 08:46:30.195  INFO 742 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2017-05-14 08:46:31.684  INFO 742 --- [           main] o.h.t.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl  : HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@7f3ca64a'
2017-05-14 08:46:31.688  INFO 742 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-05-14 08:46:33.416  INFO 742 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@77be656f: startup date [Sun May 14 08:46:26 EDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-05-14 08:46:33.560  INFO 742 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/add-buyer]}" onto public java.lang.String com.ronone.controller.BuyerController.showBuyerPager(org.springframework.ui.Model)
2017-05-14 08:46:33.561  INFO 742 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/showBuyerForm],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.ronone.controller.BuyerController.addBuyerForm(org.springframework.ui.Model)
2017-05-14 08:46:33.562  INFO 742 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/addBuyer],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.String com.ronone.controller.BuyerController.postBuyerForm(com.ronone.entities.Buyer)
2017-05-14 08:46:33.562  INFO 742 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/]}" onto public java.lang.String com.ronone.controller.MainController.homepage()
2017-05-14 08:46:33.563  INFO 742 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/add-manager]}" onto public java.lang.String com.ronone.controller.ManagerController.showManagerPage(org.springframework.ui.Model)
2017-05-14 08:46:33.564  INFO 742 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/showManagerForm],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.ronone.controller.ManagerController.addManagerForm(org.springframework.ui.Model)
2017-05-14 08:46:33.564  INFO 742 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/saveManager],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.String com.ronone.controller.ManagerController.postManagerForm(com.ronone.entities.Manager)
2017-05-14 08:46:33.564  INFO 742 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/current-stock]}" onto public java.lang.String com.ronone.controller.StockController.showStockPage(org.springframework.ui.Model)
2017-05-14 08:46:33.566  INFO 742 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/transactions]}" onto public java.lang.String com.ronone.controller.TransController.showTransPage(org.springframework.ui.Model)
2017-05-14 08:46:33.571  INFO 742 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2017-05-14 08:46:33.572  INFO 742 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2017-05-14 08:46:33.625  INFO 742 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-05-14 08:46:33.626  INFO 742 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-05-14 08:46:33.781  INFO 742 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-05-14 08:46:34.636  INFO 742 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-05-14 08:46:34.801  INFO 742 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-05-14 08:46:34.809  INFO 742 --- [           main] com.ronone.Application                   : Started Application in 19.983 seconds (JVM running for 21.058)
2017-05-14 08:46:38.074  INFO 742 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2017-05-14 08:46:38.074  INFO 742 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2017-05-14 08:46:38.097  INFO 742 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 23 ms
2017-05-14 08:46:42.610  INFO 742 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2017-05-14 08:46:43.002 ERROR 742 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-4] Exception processing template "add-manager": Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.attr.SpringInputGeneralFieldAttrProcessor' (add-manager:23)
2017-05-14 08:46:43.011 ERROR 742 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.attr.SpringInputGeneralFieldAttrProcessor' (add-manager:23)] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'manager' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:144) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatusFromParsedExpression(FieldUtils.java:401) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:328) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:294) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.attr.AbstractSpringFieldAttrProcessor.processAttribute(AbstractSpringFieldAttrProcessor.java:98) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.attr.AbstractAttrProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttrProcessor.java:87) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.AbstractProcessor.process(AbstractProcessor.java:212) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.applyNextProcessor(Node.java:1017) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:972) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Document.process(Document.java:93) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1155) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1060) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1011) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:335) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1282) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1037) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:980) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_131]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that all your methods are redirecting to the page that is showing the manager form, if this is what you want, you'll need to add the `Manager` object to the `Model` object in each of those methods :

```
@Controller
public class ManagerController {

    private ManagerService managerService;

    @Autowired
    public void setManagerService(ManagerService managerService){
        this.managerService = managerService;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/add-manager")
    public String showManagerPage(Model model){
        List<Manager> managers = managerService.findAllManagers();
        model.addAttribute("managers", managers);
        model.addAttribute("manager", new Manager());
        return "add-manager";
    }

    @GetMapping("/showManagerForm")
    public String addManagerForm(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("manager", new Manager());
        return "add-manager";
    }

    @PostMapping("/saveManager")
    public String postManagerForm(@ModelAttribute("manager") Manager manager, Model model){
        managerService.saveManager(manager);
        model.addAttribute("manager", new Manager());
        return "add-manager";
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

As M. Deinum point out, you can use the `@ModelAttribute` annotation on a method instead adding the `Manager` in each method :

```
@Controller
public class ManagerController {

    private ManagerService managerService;

    @Autowired
    public void setManagerService(ManagerService managerService){
        this.managerService = managerService;
    }

    @ModelAttribute
    public Manager manager() {
        return new Manager();
    }

    @RequestMapping("/add-manager")
    public String showManagerPage(Model model){
        List<Manager> managers = managerService.findAllManagers();
        model.addAttribute("managers", managers);
        return "add-manager";
    }

    @GetMapping("/showManagerForm")
    public String addManagerForm(Model model){
        return "add-manager";
    }

    @PostMapping("/saveManager")
    public String postManagerForm(@ModelAttribute("manager") Manager manager, Model model){
        managerService.saveManager(manager);
        return "add-manager";
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of add `model.addAttribute("manager", new Manager());` add a method annotated with `@ModelAttribute` which returns a `new Manager()` instead. Saves you adding that logic over and over.

Answer (score 0):

You are using two objects on the same page:
`manager` as a `new Manager()` instance and `managers` as a `List<Manager>`
and only adding one of them per controller route.
The following should work:

```
    @GetMapping("/showManagerForm")
    public String addManagerForm(Model model){
        List<Manager> managers = managerService.findAllManagers();
        model.addAttribute("managers", managers);
        model.addAttribute("manager", new Manager());
        return "add-manager";
    }
```